# simple Feed forward (newff) network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I used `ffnew` functions many times but when I am trying to create a simple feed forward network such that the input vector is `P=[1;2;3;4]` and the desired output is `T=[1 ;0;0;1]`. So i only have one sample input vector

The code is

```
net = newff(P,T,[4 1],{'tansig','tansig'});
net=train (net,P,T);
```

When I write the last line I got:

```
??? Error using ==> plus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> calcperf2 at 163
        N{i,ts} = N{i,ts} + Z{k};

Error in ==> trainlm at 253
[perf,El,trainV.Y,Ac,N,Zb,Zi,Zl] = calcperf2(net,X,trainV.Pd,trainV.Tl,trainV.Ai,Q,TS);

Error in ==> network.train at 216
  [net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,tr,trainV,valV,testV);
```

Comment: Is `P` a 4-dimensional sample vector or is it 4 samples of 1-dim each?

Comment: and how is the output encoded? please see the XOR example I posted.. BTW its hardly interesting to train a neural network with only one example!

Comment: I know all these things, but I want this exact code. A 4 dimensional one sample input with it's 4 dimensional desired output. I want to enter this one sample vector P and get T using feed forward.

Comment: well that exactly the problem, you are not giving the network enough samples.. try adding one more sample and it will run!

Comment: thanks, that is right. Actually I was trying to make an NN which invert a matrix [1 2;3 4], so i made it as a vector. Do you have any idea about that?
Greetings...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple example will help. Consider the famous XOR problem:

```
input = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]';               %'# each column is an input vector
ouputActual = [0 1 1 0];                     %#

net = newpr(input, ouputActual, 2);          %# 1 hidden layer with 2 neurons
net.divideFcn = '';                          %# use the entire input for training

net = init(net);                             %# init
[net,tr] = train(net, input, ouputActual);   %# train
outputPredicted = sim(net, input);           %# predict

[err,cm] = confusion(ouputActual,outputPredicted);
```

Note that I used NEWPR instead of NEWFF. The reason is that it uses a logistic function on the output (NEWFF does linear), which is more suited for classification tasks. If you use a 1-of-N target encoding, the output will be in the range [0,1] and can be interpreted as posterior probabilities for each class (NEWFF will not be restricted to [0,1])

Answer (score 1):

If you create your NN using MLP or RNN, you can change the function

`a2 = round(f2(LW2 * a1 + b2))` or `a2 = round(purelin(LW2 * a1 + b2))`

then the output NN (a2) will be binary