# fitting in neural network with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-science, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to fit a function using neural networks, with 0/1 as outputs.
please help me find the best way to it.

In fact I want to know the fitting function in MATLAB, specifically in the neural network toolbox. I don't know which method is good for modeling a function with binary output.

Also is there anyway in MATLAB that I can gain weights?

Comment: So, to clarify, you have a function that takes some inputs (on what domain?) and outputs a binary 0 or 1?  You then want to make a function (preferably via neural network) that models that function you have?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, you need to provide more details if you are to get a decent response out of the community.

Comment: please don't re-post your [question multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141223/fitting-a-function-with-neural-netwok-in-matlab)... if you didn't get the answer you were looking for the first time around, then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a [binary classification task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification) (0/1 output), then you can train a NN with two output nodes, one per class, and the trick is to use a [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) on the output node so that that its always in the range `[0,1]` (this is the default if you use `NEWPR` function). It can be interpreted as a probability, then you can use the default value `0.5` as threshold or maybe use [ROC curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) to find a better threshold for your case.

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120839/simple-feed-forward-newff-network-in-matlab/3121067#3121067) for a simple example in MATLAB of learning the XOR binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Usually neural networks are used for decision making, so a 0/1 answer is just what you want: a "yes" or a "no".

To actually fit the network one uses two sets that are known to produce a "yes" and "no" answer. Then one calculates the rates of [Type I and Type II errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) (often called purity and 1-efficiency) as a function of the network parameters.

These functions have values between 0 and 1. The goal of the fit is to find a set of network parameters which produce an acceptable balance between Type I and Type II errors while making them both as small as possible.